# Jenkins job for Deploying group of multiple servers (10 servers a group with multiple group)with a slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a Jenkins job,  we have 400 applications servers in One environment all are divided into groups like
     A = 10 servers
     B =  10 servers
     c =  10 servers ........etc.

Note : We have a Slave server(one slave) for deployment for all above parameters A,B,C...etc.
       For group A contains 10 servers which are under load balancer as well remaining B,C...etc.

while doing deployment we are choose parameter option A for deployment after completion of A we go for B deployment this is what happening.

new scenario :

While choosing A, and after B and C... we want to do all A,B,C... all at one click.the deployment has been completed. along with that we want to know how long it will take to deploy all servers (plug-in).

Can u suggest any methods:
  1.Using Jenkins Plug-in most cases
  2.Not possible with plug-in then suggest any script.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you need a distributed deployment solution to deploy an application to multiple application servers.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If this is the scenario, you need to look into solutions like puppet/salt etc.
Based on your requirement  i would suggest you look into **rundeck**.
http://rundeck.org/index.html

I've implemented distributed deployment to around 400+ servers with rundeck for my java apps. It can be easily integrated with Jenkins if you need continuous deployment. Configuring nodes is breeze. I can help you if you need support.

Comment: sure.... i need to know my manager can accept to use rundeck because another team is already working on rundeck.

Comment: Scenario : Jenkins Job for checking the content in slave machine if it exists leave it if not add this content into another server( It is not slave server ).

 This is my scenario can you help me out I can i  Process this job. How can i initiate it.

Comment: If you can give me details on what needs to be checked on the server, I can guide you. Please provide more details.

Comment: Scenario :
                  I need to create a job if I entered some name like ( CoCo-Cola is the customer) It will go and search All the servers.which contains the details of all customers they are nearly 800 servers which are running under a single slave.

           If the customer is exists in  those servers it will pop-up and shows the existing customer which we are entered.
 Otherwise it will move to other server and create an entry for the customer in that server. this server is our own live server for our reference. And 800 servers are production servers.

Comment: This is my Requirement can u suggest how Can I start working on it.